# Get distinct values from groups in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I want to get the id of the lowest points from each team (the `team` field).
My query works but i need to make sure the following query is good enough with a large table.

I need Simplification and Optimization.

### Query:

```sql
SELECT T.id from teams as T

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(T1.points) AS P FROM teams AS T1
    GROUP BY T1.team LIMIT 5
) TJOIN ON T.points IN (TJOIN.P)

GROUP BY T.team
ORDER BY T.points ASC LIMIT 5
```

### Table `teams`

| id | team (foreign_key) | points (indexed) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 100 |
| 2 | a | 101 |
| 3 | b | 106 |
| 4 | c | 105 |
| 5 | c | 102 |

### Result

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 5 |
| 3 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the query you are looking for is:

```
SELECT MIN(T.id)
FROM teams as T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT team, MIN(points) AS min_points
    FROM teams
    GROUP BY team LIMIT 5
) TJOIN
    ON T.team = TJOIN.team
    AND T.points = TJOIN.min_points
GROUP BY T.team
ORDER BY T.points ASC
LIMIT 5
```

You need to join based on both the column being grouped by and the min value. Consider the result of your query if multiple teams had a score of 100.

Another way of doing this is to use ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT id
FROM (
    SELECT id, points, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY points ASC, id ASC) rn
    FROM teams
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY points ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Both will return the lowest `id` for the lowest `points` per `team`

Comment: Run them with `EXPLAIN` and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see how much work they have to do to get your result. Experimenting and observing the results is the best way to learn!

Comment: @Jacqueline - If the answer does not work for you, don't Accept it.